# First sort rows then add temporary auto-increment column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, auto-increment

### What I like to do:

- First: sort columns according to a rule.
- Second: add an auto-increment column, so that each row will have **correct sequential numbering**.

### Issues so far:

My code below can only create the `auto-increment` column at first and only then it will start sorting. This leads to non-sequential numbering within the auto-increment column.

### Code:

```
SET @i:=0;
SELECT
    @i:=@i+1 AS autoincr_id,
    billings.id AS bill_id,
    daily_reports.id AS report_id,
    billings.billingDate AS billing_date
FROM lineitems
    INNER JOIN billings
    ON billings.order_id=lineitems.orderID
    INNER JOIN daily_reports
    ON billings.`billingDate` BETWEEN DATE_ADD(daily_reports.`referenceDate`, INTERVAL 7 HOUR ) AND DATE_ADD(daily_reports.`referenceDate`, INTERVAL 31 HOUR )
ORDER BY billings.id, autoincr_id
LIMIT 200
```

see pic that illustrates my issue

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess using a delivered table to enforce the sorting then use the variable will fix your problem.

You can also use a CROSS JOIN to init the user variable `@i` without using two queries.

**Query**

```
SELECT
    @i := @i + 1 AS autoincr_id,
    bill_id,
    report_id,
    billing_date
FROM (
    SELECT
        billings.id AS bill_id,
        daily_reports.id AS report_id,
        billings.billingDate AS billing_date
    FROM lineitems
        INNER JOIN billings
        ON billings.order_id=lineitems.orderID
        INNER JOIN daily_reports
        ON billings.`billingDate` BETWEEN DATE_ADD(daily_reports.`referenceDate`, INTERVAL 7 HOUR ) AND DATE_ADD(daily_reports.`referenceDate`, INTERVAL 31 HOUR )
    ORDER BY billings.id
    LIMIT 200
)
AS ordered
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @i := 0 ) AS init_user_param
```

Comment: Hi Raymond, your code is not runnable due to errors. Is this on purpose or do you just mean by pointing me to the right direction?

Comment: Oeps first column contains two errors `, @i := @i + 1 AS autoincr_id,` should have been `@i := @i + 1 AS autoincr_id`  try the update

Comment: Hi Raymond, I had to remove the variable autoincr_id within the nested SELECT statement since it is not needed and it is out-of-scope. Moreover I formatted your code. Please take a look and have it approved for now your code is working fine. Thanks a ton for your great support and help!
Cheng

Comment: @ChengFei You should consider accepting ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work )  the answer if it worked out.

Comment: yep, just did that. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Raymond. If I remove `LIMIT 200` the sorting via `ORDER BY billings.id` isn't consistent (sometimes the ordering for  `billings.id` is off like 100,101,104,102 ...). Do you know why `ORDER BY billings.id` is not working correctly for querying the whole table (about 30k entries/rows)

Answer (score 0):

To create a `new` table with the rows numbered in the desired order `seq_num`:

```
CREATE TABLE new (
    seq_num INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY seq_num
) ENGINE=InnoDB
    SELECT ...
        ORDER BY ...
```

Caveat:  `AUTO_INCREMENT` will not have consecutive ids if you are in a multi-Master replication setup.  This is because of `auto_increment_increment` won't be `1`.

Comment: your approach suggests that I need to create and add a new table to the database. I only need the new order column to be shown in a ResultSet since I need to export it into a csv file; I am not supposed to modify the existing db in any way.

Comment: @ChengFei - OK; then my answer is more for other readers, than for you.